# How to assign values to Boolean object

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression

I really don't like to ask questions and be dependent on others, but I have to !
I need an input from the user of in between two and five words, designated by fontvorto1, fontvorto2, fontvorto3, fontvorto4 and fontvorto5.
I have to be sure, that he/she does not leave empty an in-between text field.
So at each input trial I check by onclick whether the field above has been filled in. If not, the user gets an alert and the input is broken off.
To minimize the amount of code I created five functions of the following model:

```
    function fV2k() {x = document.getElementsByName('fontvorto1')[0].value.substr(0, 6); return Boolean(x == "Skribu" || x === "");}
    function fV3k() {x = document.getElementsByName('fontvorto2')[0].value.substr(0, 6); return  Boolean(x == "Skribu" || x === "");}
```

and so on up to fV25, where "Skribu" is the initial valu of the text input fields fontvorto1, fontvorto2 and so on.
The onclick of the input fields read:

```
    onclick="if(fV2k()){alert(admonition);} else {this.value='';}"
```

but that does not work. Also

```
    onclick="p = fV2k(); if(p){alert(admonition);} else {this.value='';}"
```

does not work.
So I struggled through some tutorial about booleans and boolean objects and I concluded that I should create "var p = new Boolean()".
Now I have:

```
    var p = new Boolean();
function fV2k() {x = document.getElementsByName('fontvorto2')[0].value.substr(0, 6); p = Boolean(x == "Skribu" || x === "");}
function fV3k() {x = document.getElementsByName('fontvorto2')[0].value.substr(0, 6); p = Boolean(x == "Skribu" || x === "");}
```

and so on, which is wrong of course because I should treat p as a function and not assign a value here.
Every time I introduce an "innovation", I feel optimistic that now I solve the problem, but each time my hope is shattered.
I hope I have been clear and that some "specialist" likes this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. Your function should just test the value and return the result, like this:

```
function fV3k() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName('fontvorto2')[0].value.substr(0, 6); 
    return x === "Skribu" || x === "";
}
```

Or possibly take in the name as a parameter, so you can reduce the total number of function you need to write:

```
function fV(name) {
    var x = document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value.substr(0, 6); 
    return x === "Skribu" || x === "";
}
```

And then use it as

```
onclick="if(fV('fontvorto1')){alert(admonition);} else {this.value='';}"
...
onclick="if(fV('fontvorto2')){alert(admonition);} else {this.value='';}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, p.s.w.g. ! I started as simple as you now suggested, but for some, now unidentifiable reason, it did not work.

Comment: @user2772060 Well unless you're having issues implementing this exact solution, you should probably open another question. Before you do though, you should try to make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the full problem, and duplicates the issue.